# Replace a Word, but Only on a Specific Line

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

In my application  i have to replace some words from text which appears more then one line.My text is

```
Most at-home desensitizing toothpastes work by
primarily numbing the nerve and masking the pain
Traditional potassium iron-based toothpastes in the
form of potassium nitrate, potassium citrate.
```

I want to replace "potassium" in 3rd line with "" only.My code is

```
string text = t.Replace("potassium", "");
```

The problem is that the word is removed from all lines.

How to replace any one word from a paragraph from a specific line ?

Comment: Do you store your lines in one String?

Comment: why you don't want pottassium in the fourth line to be removed?

Comment: Because due to an API's output only this word is wrongly placed

Comment: Does the string have any line breaks to identify new lines? If it has you can split by line breaks, then replace specific word in specific line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first look at the regex ([demo here](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=f2fda7e4-02d8-498e-89f5-5e1caa1e87b8)). Then you can change the parameters programmatically.

This regex targets the first `potassium` on the third line:

```
(?<=\A(?:[^\r\n]*\r?\n+){2}[^\r\n]*?)potassium
```

This replaces it with `bromide`:

```
replaced = Regex.Replace(yourString, @"(?<=\A(?:[^\r\n]*\r?\n+){2}[^\r\n]*?)potassium", "bromide");
```

To replace all the `potassium` on the third line, we use `\G`:

```
(?<=\A([^\r\n]*\r?\n+){2}[^\r\n]*?|\G[^\r\n]*?)potassium
```

**With Parameters: Replacing Any Word on Any Line**

To replace word `someword` on line `n`, build the regex string programmatically. In the regex you must use `n-1`, as this is the number of lines we skip.

```
var myRegex = new Regex(@"(?<=\A(?:[^\r\n]*\r?\n+){" + (n-1) + @"}[^\r\n]*?)" + someword );
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=\A([^\r\n]*\r?\n+){2}[^\r\n]*?)` is a big lookbehind that asserts we can find something behind the current position (at which we'll match the literal `potassium`)
- `\A` asserts that we're at the beginning of the string
- `(?:[^\r\n]*\r?\n+)` matches any number of chars that are not newline characters, followed by a newline
- The `{2}` quantifier matches that twice, getting us to line 3
- `[^\r\n]*?` lazily matches any number of non-new line chars (we're now on line 3)
- Having asserted all that, we can match `potassium`
- in Option 2, where we match all the `potassium` on the line, `|\G[^\r\n]*?` inside the lookbehind says **OR** what precedes us is the position immediately after the previous match, then any number of non-newline chars.

Comment: Thanks, glad it works! FYI, added explanation **AND** a variation to replace **all** instances of `potassium` on line 3, not just the first one.

Comment: Small demo just in case. :) [regex demo](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=f2fda7e4-02d8-498e-89f5-5e1caa1e87b8)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest but not the best:

```
var multiLineString = "Most at-home desensitizing toothpastes work by" + Environment.NewLine +
    "primarily numbing the nerve and masking the pain" + Environment.NewLine +
    "Traditional potassium iron-based toothpastes in the" + Environment.NewLine +
    "form of potassium nitrate, potassium citrate.";

var lines = multiLineString
    .Split(Environment.NewLine);

lines[lines.Length-1] = lines[lines.Length-1].Replace("potassium ", "");

var resultingLine = String.Join(lines, Environment.NewLine))
```

Comment: Why not even simpler `lines[2].Replace(...)`?

Comment: Yes, I just thought the potassium was in other lines as well.

Comment: Might be, but he says he wants to replace in third line only, not the opposite way round.

Comment: That's irrelevant now. But I'll rectify it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The below regex would match the string pottassium present only in the third line,

```
potassium(?!\s*\w+[.,])
```

And your code would be,

```
replaced = Regex.Replace(yourString, @"potassium(?!\s*\w+[.,])", "");
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iA3rG0)